# Visualización de porcentajes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hace unos días tenía un problema con visualización de valores, ahora tengo un problema con la visualización completa.

Tengo este código:

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DataFrame de ejemplo
X = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Corpoemprende\Programas sociales\Libro3.csv', encoding='latin1')

IDNivelEducativo_Programas = X.groupby(['ID_Nivel_Educativo','Programas_Conocidos']).size()
IDNivelEducativo_Programas = IDNivelEducativo_Programas.reset_index()
IDNivelEducativo_Programas = pd.pivot_table(IDNivelEducativo_Programas, columns = 'ID_Nivel_Educativo', index = 'Programas_Conocidos', values = 0)
GraficoX = IDNivelEducativo_Programas.plot(kind = 'bar', 
                                           stacked = True, 
                                           figsize=(20, 15), 
                                           #grid = True, 
                                           title="Cantidad de personas que según nivel educativo conocen programas sociales")
    
plt.legend(loc=0, bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 1.0), title="Nivel_Educativo")

plt.xlabel('Programas_Conocidos')
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')

abs_values = IDNivelEducativo_Programas.values
rel_values = abs_values / abs_values.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True) * 100

labels = zip(abs_values.T.flatten(), rel_values.T.flatten())

for rec in GraficoX.patches:
    abs_value, rel_value = next(labels)
    label = f"{abs_value:.0f}, ({rel_value:.1f}%)"
    width, height = rec.get_width(), rec.get_height()
    x, y = rec.get_xy()
    GraficoX.text(x=x + width / 2,
                  y=y + height / 2,
                  s=label,
                  ha='center', 
                  va='center',
                  fontsize = 10)
    
#GraficoX.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 105, 5))
#GraficoX.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0, 100, 1), rotation=360) #np.arange(0, 11, 1)

plt.savefig(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\%_Barras_acumuladas2.png', dpi=250)
plt.show()
```

Me genera este plot:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro visualizar todos los porcentajes en cada barra (en los colores verde, morado y café solo está `nan%`).

¿Alguna ayuda o consejo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado el problema:

Luego de la línea:

```
IDNivelEducativo_Programas = pd.pivot_table(IDNivelEducativo_Programas, columns = 'ID_Nivel_Educativo', index = 'Programas_Conocidos', values = 0)
```

Adicono la línea, que me llena los espacios 'nan' con 0 (ceros):

```
IDNivelEducativo_Programas = IDNivelEducativo_Programas.fillna(0)
```

Y así obtengo todos los valores absolutos y porcentuales.

C.